# How to append jQuery Masonry on ajax loaded Content?

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax

I'm using [Infinite Scroll · jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html) to implement infinite scroll, the code execute perfectly good on load(content via ajax) but the problem is that on scroll, it does not give right alignment ie jQuery Masonry is not appended..How to append jQuery Masonry on ajax loaded Content?
here is my index page Code link:
http://chopapp.com/#ty0jcg2g

and ajax content is loaded via:
http://chopapp.com/#efctqpgn